# Delete all tables of Database

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a Database named **KG**. I want to delete all tables in this Database using java and then create them again (purpose is to truncate ALL data. Deleting tables as per advice of someone here at stackoverflow). What i need is a single command that can delete all tables. From [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-drop-tables.htm) link i took this command

> Drop Database KG

This command is not working with my case. Is there any other way to delete all Tables?

**Editted**

Code I am Using is

```
   {
        dbConnect();
        try {
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            sql = "Drop Database KG";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            c.commit();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
            System.out.println("Database Deleted!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Delete Database Query: " + sql);
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
   }
```

and

```
public void dbConnect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:KG.s3db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Error i am getting is

> Delete Database: Drop Database KG
>
> java.sql.SQLException: near "Database": syntax error

**Note:**

I have achieved it but by writing a large number of Lines of Code. Used command

> Drop Table If Exists *tablename*

did this in loop.

Comment: `drop database KG;` *should* work, but how are you actually *running* that command?  As in, can we see the actual `executeUpdate` method call, and the code leading up to that?

Comment: And in what way does it "not work"? Doesn't do anything? Throws an Exception?

Comment: I am not doing android, it is for Win app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not drop a sqlite database. Just delete the database file and open the database again.

Comment: how to delete Database? is there an sql command or using FILE library of java?

Comment: You can use the **Files.delete(path)** with Java

Comment: Well, that i guessed. Thanks.